# How to find the last row of an array with a non-empty cell?

Tags: google-sheets

//Sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wWZa05kIJ8F8r3EojxObmtiRM5KcgCR7KAyMmHh6KU/edit?usp=sharing)

Hi,

I am using formulas to calculate an array N:R. Once calculated, I want to determine the last row of the array with a non-empty cell (the empty cells are not blank).

What I can do so far:

Return the last non-empty cell of a column

```
=INDEX(FILTER(O:O,O:O<>""), ROWS(FILTER(O:O,O:O<>"")))
```

or the row of the filter selection (in my case 25 in the filter selection vs 38 in the sheet)

```
=ROWS(FILTER(O:O,O:O<>""))
```

What I haven't figured out is how to:

1. Do this search for the whole array and not just one row at a time
2. Return the row of the last non-empty cell in the array

Cheers

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you want to achieve here. It looks to me that you figured out not to "Return the last non-empty cell of a row" but rather "… of a column". Do you want to search for the last row of a multi-column array where there are non-empty cells in a) all columns of  this row b) any column of this row? Also you indicate in your example that the last non-zero item of the array is row 35, whereas I can see it as row 38. Confusing. Perhaps a simpler example sheet would help.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right (just edited it, the first formula I give does indeed return the last non-empty cell of a column). What I am trying to accomplish is return the row number of the last non-empty cell in an multicolumn array. In the sheet it should be 38 as you mentioned (also highlighted it in the example a bit better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a formulaic approach, you can try

```
=max(filter(row(N2:N), MMULT(N(N2:R<>""), transpose(column(N2:R2)^0))>0))
```

Comment: I never cease to be amazed at what people do with formulas! Takes a seriously twisted mind I say:-). Good work.

Comment: That's great! Works perfectly. I'm trying to understand the formula by going from the inside out. Why is there a need for arrayformula? Using =filter(row(N2:N), MMULT(N(N2:R<>""), transpose(column(N2:R2)^0))>0) delivers the same output except for the first element of the array being a '2'). Also in terms of MMULT(N(N2:R<>""), transpose(column(N2:R2)^0))>0; wouldn't the argument for transpose always result in '1' (unless empty^0 gives a different result or 0^0). Read about the N function, but can't see to make sense of N(N2:R<>"") if N2:R is not empty it returns a '1'? Thanks

Comment: Correct, @jlo. Creating the MMULT (that needed the array formula) was my first step in creating this formula. Forgot to remove it afterward. The MMULT counts the number of non-empty cells per row. Then filter is used to filter out the row numbers where the MMULT returned 0 (=empty rows). Then MAX() returns the highest row number. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This custom function will do it. Sometimes scripts are way easier than some of the bizarre formulas that arise (IMHO). It just loops through the data row by row and notes the row number if it finds data ie `cell.value() != ""`

```
function findHighestNonEmptyRow(dummyRange){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = sheet.getRange("N:R");
  var valuesRC = range.getValues();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

  var highestNonEmptyRow = 0;

  for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      if (valuesRC[row][col] != ""){
        highestNonEmptyRow = row+1;  // +1 to offset loop variable
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(highestNonEmptyRow);
  return highestNonEmptyRow;
}
```

Log show correct value of `38`. You can delete the  `Logger.log(highestNonEmptyRow)`; line when you have tested.

I put the formula in `W44` in your test sheet....

EDIT: Due to feedback that all was not as expected...

1. There was a typo in the first script:    This line `var range =
   sheet.getRange("N:D");`    should have been `var range =
   sheet.getRange("N:R");`
2. I found out that Google scripts caches the result of custom
   formulas, and just returns the cached value, even if things on the
   sheet have changed. This is bizarre behavior, but is intended to
   reduce CPU time. The workaround is to pass in a range that is likely
   to change, and this causes the function to recalculate. I updated
   the formula and the called the function like this:

   ```
   =findHighestNonEmptyRow(N2:R42)
   ```

   and hey it all works!
3. Stick to the formula...  however, we both learned a lot from your
   question I think, so thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way where the custom formula would get updated automatically when the cells have changed? For example, in the sheet, I deleted the cell in row 38 (so the new result would be row 37 -the last non-empty cell now-) and the formulaic approach gets updated to 37 but findHighestNonEmptyRow() won't

Comment: I would have assumed the custom formula would update after an edit, but if not it can be made to via an onEdit trigger. But if you are happy with the JPV formula then use it, no worries!  Let me know if you want me to make any improvements,

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with onEdit triggers, I thought custom formulas updated themselves automatically, but apparently not. Cheers!